# Why I can't perform buffer overflow directly from bash

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow

Maybe is a silly question but I can't understand exactly why this type of buffer overflow does not work...

Let's me explain with an example.

Suppose we have a program written in c.
This program has 2 function , normal() and  special(). In main function we have a pointer which points in address of normal function. Also it has an array we 5 bytes which we fill using gets and after that we
Call the pointer which has the address of normal () . Our goal is to perform buffer overflow which overwrite the content of the pointer with the address of function special.

So when I write a python script like
python-c " A*5 + <address_of_special> " | myprogram I successfully perform an buffer overflow calling the special function.

However, when I try to run the program without the script, for example
./myprogram AAAAA + address_of_special I get segmentation  fault and the program crash.

Why this happens ; I mean the program gets the same input but I have different results ...

Comment: It's not the same input. Passing data thru a pipe is not the same as passing as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is passing data to the programs `stdin` pipe, which is what `gets` reads from. The second example is passing the data as a parameter (which gets stored in the `argv` parameter of `main`, if there is one), and `gets` will fail to read anything (unless you type some stuff while the program is running).

You absolutely can perform the buffer overflow directly from the shell. One option is to use the `printf` shell command, which works similarly to the C function of the same name, and then pipe that to the the program: `printf 'AAAAA\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4' | myprogram` will feed the ASCII string "AAAAA" followed by four bytes (in little-endian, 0xB4B3B2B1), which you'd make the address of `special`, to your program just the same as Python does. Another option (for Bash and things like it) is to store the exact string you want to send (which may include unprintable characters!) either in a string, file, or variable, and then do `myprogram <<< 'AAAAA&,´æ` (or similar), `myprogram << filename`, or `myprogram <<< $variable`, respectively (each of those also causes the shell to feed some data to the program's `stdin`).

Comment: Thank you very much for you response , I appreciate it. If I try to put the input through gets, when the program is running , why I have the same error ; For example , if I run the program and  after I type in gets  --> AAAAA\x11\x11\x11\x11 I get segmentation  fault.

Comment: That's because your program is receiving the binary value for ASCII literal backslashes, x characters, and 1s. You have to either pass the desired binary values directly to the program (typically, though not always, by first decoding them through a command like `printf`), or you need to decode the escape sequences in your C code (there's probably a safer way to do this than `sprintf` but hey, it's not like your program is going to get a lot *less* secure). Of course, you might have trouble calling a formatting function on a buffer that has already overflowed.